# action.payload.descrition shows 'undefined' when using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello I'm new to redux and this is my first redux code.

My index.js:

```
    import store from './store'

    store.dispatch({
        type:"bugAdded",
        payload: {
          decription: "THIS"
        }
     });
```

My reducer.js:

```
let lastId = 0;

function reducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'bugAdded':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: ++lastId,
          description: action.payload.description,
          resolved: false,
        }
      ];
    case 'bugRemoved':
      return state.filter(bug => bug.id !== action.payload.id)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer

console.log(store.getState());
```

My store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducer'

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store
```

As per the tutorial I'm supposed to get

```
description: THIS
```

in console log, whereas I'm getting

```
description: undefined
```

[image: console.log screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. You're dispatching:

```js
payload: {
          decription: "THIS"
        }
```

it should be `description` instead.

Also, note that the style of Redux code you're writing is very outdated. Today we teach using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) as the standard approach for using Redux, which will simplify all of the code in your app (even in this small example).

See the official Redux docs tutorials for details:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Answer (score 1):

import store from './store'

store.dispatch({
type:"bugAdded",
payload: {
decription: "THIS"
}
});

in you index.js file, you type wrong **decription** it must be **description**